# Google Play Developer Console dashboard, where is it?

Tags: android

I've been searching on stackoverflow and other places, but all I find is that the dashboard has been updated and it's accessible from developer console listings page. All I see next to my app is "x total installs" etc, no link to any dashboard?

Answer (score 5):

The developer dashboard is located here https://play.google.com/apps/publish/ (login to your google account).
For more information about a specific app, click on Comments, Statistics or Errors.

Answer (score 1):

An update on this: It looks like the total installs and active installs update on different times and you have to have enough stats for the statistics button to show up. There really should be something like "not enough stats" before that, it's confusing..